# What is the idiomatic way to handle variadic values in a variable assignment?

Tags: lua

I have some code that wants to do grab some extra return values from a function and pass them forward latter on:

```
local ok, ... = coroutine.resume(co)
do_stuff(ok)
return ...
```

However, this won't run since the `...` on the variable assignment is a syntax error.

I could work around this limitation by using the old "functions arguments and variables are equivalent" trick and an immediately-invoked function

```
return (function(ok, ...)
    do_stuff(ok)
    return ...
)(coroutine.resume(co))
```

but I imagine doing so wouldn't be very idiomatic or efficient. Are there more reasonable ways to solve this problem of handling the remaining values returned from the `resume` call?

EDIT: By the way, this needs to work with `nil` values in the extra arguments

**EDIT2:** Looks like using the immediately invoked function was the best way all along.

Comment: Passing through a function will be more efficient than creating a table to temporarily hold the values. However, if you're concerned with efficiency, you should define the wrapper function before hand (or just in time) and only once, rather than creating a new closure every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the best way is passing vararg as parameter to helper function as you have done in your question.
The alternative way is "pack-unpack":

```
-- Lua 5.2 only
local t = table.pack(coroutine.resume(co))
do_stuff(t[1])
return table.unpack(t, 2, t.n)
```

Comment: I did some benchmarks and it looks like the weird vararg parameter solution really is faster too. You need to do extra work and function calls if you want to pass things via a table...

Comment: @missingno - A curious off-topic.  In vanilla Lua the fastest way to create a copy of an array is `local t_copy = {unpack(t)}`.  :)

Comment: @missingno: The vararg solution is going to be faster because it doesn't require a table creation.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to do this with an unknown number of return values is to wrap the function call in a table constructor:

```
local t = { coroutine.resume(co) }
do_stuff(table.remove(t, 1)) 
return unpack(t)  -- table.unpack(t) in lua 5.2
```

While this also involves creating a temporary object, it should be a lot quicker than using a closure, and it's certainly a lot neater.

Comment: table.remove may behave unpredictably if there are nil-values inside t

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Technically, if there are `nil` values in `t`, then `unpack` will also behave unpredictably. So there's not much choice here.

Comment: @NicolBolas - use full form `unpack(t, from, to)` to avoid unpredictability.